# Splitting a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Most Keras scripts I have seen so far, require a dataset which is already separated into a training, validation and test set. The data is then usually loaded by a snippet like the following:

```
train_files, train_targets = load_dataset('/data/train')
valid_files, valid_targets = load_dataset('/data/validation')
test_files, test_targets = load_dataset('/data/test')
```

That works well if the dataset is already split, but what If my dataset is not split in this way and just has the following structure:

```
data
  - cats
  - dogs
```

Is there a buildin Keras method to split such as dataset into a train, validation and test set?

Comment: you can use ```sklearn``` library to split into train and test. For more please check this function ```sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split```

Comment: I know, I just wanted to know if there is a buildin Keras method.